# How do you compile libssh, mysql and net-snmp in one Makefile for Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, gcc, net-snmp

I'm writing a program to monitor a few network switches. Today I tried added the libssh library to the project, but can't seem to get it to compile. It seems like a simple thing, but I couldn't find the answer googling.

I was able to compile a test program with the command.

```
gcc libssh.c -lssh
```

I can't seem to get the -lssh to work in my makefile.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.

LIBS=`net-snmp-config --libs` `mysql_config --cflags --libs` `-lssh`

TARGET = snmpmon

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c $(LIBS)

clean:
        $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

I guessing it's something simple any suggestion?

```
gcc -I. -o snmpmon snmpmon.c `net-snmp-config --libs` `mysql_config --cflags --libs` `-lssh --libs`
/bin/sh: 1: -lssh: not found
/tmp/cc65Loeb.o: In function `GetMACinfo':
snmpmon.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `ssh_new'
snmpmon.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `ssh_options_set'
snmpmon.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `ssh_options_set'
snmpmon.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `ssh_options_set'
snmpmon.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `ssh_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'snmpmon' failed
make: *** [snmpmon] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

OK the issue was `-lssh` should be -lssh the makefile didn't like the extra ` marks.